# How to Pass Upstream Job Build Parameters to Downstream Jobs configured in a MultiJob Phase?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Upstream Job(MultiJob) which takes a String Parameter called freshORrerun, to take string value as "fresh" or "rerun" string value, which i need to pass on to downstream(standalone build) jobs to check the value is "fresh" or "rerun". Based on which, in child jobs's i will trigger complete tests run (pybot) or rerun (rebot) of failed tests.

here i have attached the screenshots how i have configured. When i print the passed string in child job it is empty.

Overall Job configuration.
[image]

Multi Job phase config and child Jobs
[image]

I have many no.of robot tests running them takes a lot of time. i need a way to run only failures of previous run, so that it gives me quick picture of how many got fixed. Could Some one please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'Add parameters' button, select 'predefined parameters' and add: freshORrerun=${freshORrerun} to the list.

Comment: Great answer! The curly brackets are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using one plugin called `parameterized job trigger` in which you will get options to pass parent job parameters to child job.

Note:- For this, you have to create parameters in child job also. These parameters will be overwritted.

[plugin link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)